# How to find USB Storage device PATH based on serial number?

Tags: rhel, lsusb

If I find a serial number in `/var/log/dmesg` e.g `SerialNumber: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`. How can I find the device and the path to this device?

Do I need to enable the kernel module `usb-storage`? What will that do for me and how do I make it persistent?

I've tried to use `lsusb` but the storage device doesn't seem to appear. I can however see it in dmesg without any errors.
I need to find the USB storage device and make a file system on it.

Comment: Well, there must be something I'm missing since it seems so obvious that if you want to use a usb storage device, you need the usb-storage driver to be loaded.

Comment: @MC68020 … and on every desktop linux since ca 2000, that module gets automatically loaded by udev or a similar mechanism. There's exactly nothing that a user of RHEL (see the tags) needs to manually do to enable USB storage device support in their operating system.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is a RHEL7 server, and I cannot see that the module is loaded when the system boots.

Comment: @user1098490 as said thrice now, your system will automatically load it, as soon as a correctly working USB storage device is plugged in.

Comment: OK then whatever, already loaded or not, modprobe it & tell us what happens

Comment: And also if you can copy/paste your boot command line.

Comment: Looks like a task for `udev`rules (instead of trying to read/parse `syslog`)

Comment: @EduardoTrápani he's using RHEL. RHEL has the necessary rules. This isn't an experimental operating system. This is a fully fledged distro. This is Redhat. Kind of the mother of all end-user distros.

Comment: @MarcusMüller the OP stated *"I need to find the USB storage device and make a file system on it."* so I thought the idea was to capture the serial number from the log, find the device and do a `mkfs` on it (dangerous, alright, but that's what the OP seemed to be after). If RHEL has that situation covered ... well, I'll erase my comment, because it doesn't add anything useful.

Comment: Based on the description, I'd just use `lsblk` to find the drive (if necessary comparing before and after plugging it in).

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to enable the kernel module usb-storage? What will that do for me and how do I make it persistent?

No. Any Linux kernel you'd find these days will have that module or compiled in, and the system will load it if necessary.

Doubly so if you're on RHEL, as your tag indicates.

> I've tried to use lsusb but the storage device doesn't seem to appear.

Then the computer doesn't see it as working USB device at all, so you have a hardware problem.

> can however see it in dmesg without any errors.

If there's no errors, then dmesg will tell you there's a storage device of a specific size, including its device names.

If that doesn't happen, your storage device is broken and nothing Linux can do changes that.

Comment: how can I keep the kernel module after system reboot? I've tried following RedHat section 1.7, without getting it working(https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/kernel_administration_guide/chap-documentation-kernel_administration_guide-working_with_kernel_modules#sec-Loading-kernel-modules-automatically-at-system-boot-time). And... let say if my device appears using the lsusb how do I find the /dev path for this device?...

Comment: your question makes no sense. You don't need to load a kernel module. Please make sure you've actually read my answer! Because I explictly address both things you ask in your comment  already in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you see e.g.:

```
usb 1-1: Product: DT 100 G2
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

note the USB path prefix (`1-1` in this example).

It should be followed by messages like:

```
usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host6: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
```

The first line indicates that the configuration 1, interface 0 of that device has been identified as an USB Storage device, and the `usb-storage` driver module has been autoloaded and has taken control of it. That driver presents it as a SCSI-compatible storage device as `scsi host6`, as indicated by the second line.

If the `usb-storage` module does not load, this step and any subsequent steps won't happen, and the device won't be accessible as a storage device.

Then the generic SCSI layer identifies the device in turn:

```
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DT 100 G2        PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
scsi 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
```

Note the SCSI four-part identifier: `6:0:0:0` = Host 6, controller/bus 0, target 0, LUN 0 is now associated with the USB storage device. In case you needed to access it with raw SCSI commands, you could do it using the `/dev/sg0` device.

```
sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] 31342592 512-byte logical blocks: (16.0 GB/14.9 GiB)
sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
  sda: sda1
sd 6:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

After that, the usual disk storage driver detects it is an actual disk-like storage device, and presents it as /dev/`sda`. It also detected that the USB storage device has a partition table with just one partition, as indicated by the `sda: sda1` line. If the disk had e.g. three partitions, it might look like `sda: sda1 sda2 sda3` instead.

---

There are two common reasons why the `usb-storage` module might not load when plugging in a USB storage device:

- the device is broken and no longer recognizable as an USB storage device
- the system is "hardened" for extra security, and the automatic loading of the `usb-storage` module has been intentionally disabled.

If you suspect it might be the former, try a different USB storage device. If the device does not appear in `lsusb` listing, a hardware fault is the most likely explanation, because it means the device cannot complete even the most low-level USB identification.

If it's the latter, **stop** and make sure you are actually allowed to plug in your USB storage device into that specific server before proceeding further. Hardening generally suggests the server might be providing some critical service, which might have special requirements on technical, administrative (change control/audit) or legal level. Unauthorized tampering on such a server can be a quick way to lose your job and/or get sued, depending on jurisdiction. Better safe than sorry.

---

The usual way to disable kernel modules in most hardening instructions is to add a line in some `/etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` file, such as:

```
install usb-storage /bin/true   #could be also /bin/false
```

This replaces the actual loading of the module with a do-nothing command, disabling the automatic loading for this module.

Commenting out the line (and running `depmod` in older distributions) is often enough to undo the restriction, and then the USB storage device should be detectable by unplugging & re-plugging it. But make sure you have the proper authorization and have completed any necessary change management steps before doing that.